# Pandas drop rows that do not contains list of strings

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file with this data structure:

```
timestamp.  message.         name.   destinationUserName sourceUserName 
time.        login.          hello.    
time.        logout.         hello
time.        successful      hello1
time.        hello.          no
time.        notsuccessful   no
```

In my current code, I am Able to filter the `name` columns base on if it contains `hello` or `hello1`.. but what I would like to do, is to not only check `name` but be able to check `message` column and return only the messages that contains `successful` or `notsuccesful`.

so far I have this code:

```
f=pd.read_csv('file.csv')
f = f[f['name'].isin(names_to_keep)]
```

this works just perfect returning all the names that contains a list of the name I declared in `names_to_keep`. So I tried to update the code to add messages using

```
f = f[f['name'].isin(names_to_keep & f[f['message'].isin(message_to_keep)])]
```

In this case using the `&` it return an empty document because in the current file I don't have any `message` with that string, which is fine, but I am expecting the script to return the `names` even if there is no `message` machine the code.

I hope my example is clear enough, and please if you need more information just let me know.

expected result:

```
timestamp.  message.         name.   destinationUserName sourceUserName 
time.        login.          hello.    
time.        logout.         hello
time.        successful      hello1
time.        notsuccessful   no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return rows where the name column contains a value from a list of values or the message column contains a value from a list of values you can use this.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

names_to_keep =  ['hello', 'hello1', 'hello2']

messages_to_keep = ['successful', 'notsuccessful']

print(df)

df = df[df['name'].isin(names_to_keep) 
 | df['message'].isin(messages_to_keep)]

print(df)
```

```
Sample Input
  timestamp        message    name destinationuserna
0      time          login   hello             user1
1      time         logout  hello1             user2
2      time     successful  hello2             user3
3      time          hello      no             user3
4      time  notsuccessful   don't            random
```

```
Sample Output
0      time          login   hello             user1         8-8103
1      time         logout  hello1             user2         8-8103
2      time     successful  hello2             user3         8-8103
4      time  notsuccessful   don't            random         8-8103
```

Comment: The `&` in my case is a condition that return the wrong result. Because to output the rows, both name and messages need to return true. Is there a way to use `or` instead of `&`

Comment: I updated my post with the desired output. In which I believe a OR condition should solve the problem

Comment: Yesss that was what I was looking for. I was using the wrong or.. I was using `||`. Thank you so much my friend.